# Spring boot multi module project: Intellij Build error

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea, maven-module

I have a multi module maven project.

I can do maven compile of my Spring project without any error.
However, when I try to run using IntelliJ, it shows error that it can't find packages from the other module!

Comment: try invalidate cache https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html

Comment: What is the IDE version? Does **Reload** from Maven tool window complete successfully? Provide more context for the error: including the exact error message and describe how you configure the relationships between the modules from which packages are not found. Or provide a sample project.

Comment: Hi, can you take a screenshot of your Modules configuration in File -> Project Structure (Ctrl + Alt + Maj + S) ?